# My mic is picking up and playing back any and all sound

Tags: laptop, microphone, dell-inspiron

I have an Inspiron 17.3" laptop. I run Windows 7. My internal mic is picking up all sound and playing it back, which it then picks up again and plays back again. I've had to turn off my mic entirely and I can no longer use Skype or Google voice search. Any help?

Comment: Sounds like the mic is damaged.  You will have to use an external microphone.

Answer (score 3):

There could be many reasons to why this is happening, one it could be a defect mic like @Ramhound mentioned.

---

Right click on the speaker icon > *Recording Devices* > *Recording* > select your mix > click on *Properties* > *Listen* > uncheck *Listen to this device*

---

[image]

[image]

[image]